# In CakePHP 3, how can I use the UrlHelper in a Shell to generate an URL?

Tags: shell, cakephp

To use Emails, I just

```
use Cake\Network\Email\Email;
$email = new Email();
```

but trying that with UrlHelper is unsuccessful.

As unsuccessful is with a

```
$url_helper = new UrlHelper;
```

because it gives me

```
Argument 1 passed to Cake\View\Helper::__construct() must be an instance of Cake\View\View.
```

But I don't have View in Shell, I suppose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a helper in the shell is not the right way to approach this. The helper as well is just wrapping [the Router](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.Routing.Router.html). So instead use the Router directly:

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
$url = Router::url([/*...*/], true);
```

Also note that you can change the base URL as needed by calling `Router::fullBaseUrl()`, it's a getter and setter. See the [documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#645-670).

This is better because:

- It's introducing less dependencies
- Less tight coupling (OK, you get a singleton instead...)
- Doesn't violate MVC
- Smaller footprint

Comment: I was not aware the Url Helper encapsulates the Router, so I am in agreement with you on dependencies and coupling, however I politely disagree on breaking MVC convention, as the scope of a Shell script doesn't fit particularly well within any of the three letters in the paradigm.  A shell script could be argued as being business logic, but most shells will still exist as an abstraction of Table level logic that accepts arguments in much the same way a controller would accept inputs from a request object.  I would love to hear your thoughts, Burzum.

Comment: A shell can be seen as a kind of controller but there is not really a "view" layer. I totally disagree with "but most shells will still exist as an abstraction of Table level logic" if it would be "table" logic, it should be implemented in a table (or other model layer object) and used as such. That a view (there are shell helpers as well) requires a view object to work should be a clear indicator that it should (technically it can) not be used in a shell. A shell method should be skinny and some other "M" layer type of class should do the work.

Comment: Agreed - I think I misrepresented myself.  What I meant by Shell implementation of Table logic is an implementation of logic defined within the Table objects themselves, whereas the shell acts as a skinny controller, taking arguments from command line and then delegating those arguments to the Table objects themselves to do the heavy lifting.  I appreciate your input Burz, have a happy New Year!

Answer (score -1):

You could probably follow a similar method for mocking out a helper in the shell as they do for mocking out a helper for unit testing.  Try:

```
<?php

use Cake\View\View;
use Cake\View\Helper\UrlHelper;

class FooShell extends Shell
{
    public $url_helper = null;

    public function bar()
    {
        $view = new View();
        $this->url_helper = new UrlHelper($view);
        // URL Helper functionality created here
    }
}
```

Here is the docs I used for [mocking out a helper in CakePHP 3](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-helpers).